# Google Apps Script does not load when embedded into iFrame

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

I am trying to embed my Google Apps Script WebApp into an iFrame on another domain but the webapp is not loaded and I only see a white screen. There is also no error in the webinspector.

The Webapp is published with: **Execute as m**e and **Access has anyone within Given Domain.**

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setXFrameOptionsMode(XFrameOptionsMode)) I implemented my doGet method like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
 return HtmlService
 .createHtmlOutputFromFile('html/index')
 .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

and the IFrame looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://script.google.com/a/my_domain/macros/s/ADjidojcojv/exec" title="test" width="558" height="300"></iframe>
```

When the user is logged into Google the webapp is displayed. However when the user is not logged in a grey image with `account.google.com refused to connect`

I think the reason is that there is a redirect to the google sign in which does not allow to be displayed. Furthermore in this case there is also another redirect to a SAML SSO application. So when you normally sign in into google you will redirect to the SAML SSO login.

What are my options here?

[Edit]
I found someone with the [exact same problem](https://joshuatz.com/posts/2019/google-apps-script-authorization-in-a-cross-origin-iframe/) and one possible solution. Apparently there is no easy way of doing this...

Comment: Is the published app accessible incognito without the frame?

Comment: well I need to be logged into google to access it

Comment: *into an iFrame on another domain*. Is this "another domain" = "given domain"?

Comment: no, they are different

Comment: Then you have your answer. Another domain doesn't have access to given domain.

Comment: I don't follow, the domain does not need access, the user does, so if the user is logged into google then it should work right?

Comment: Not as easy as that. Check your browser console.Devtools>console. Refresh page

Comment: Is the user that is trying to access this Web App in your domain?. According to [this piece of documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) only those users in your domain can access the app.

Comment: yes the user of the domain still can only see a white page in the iFrame. Also the Devtool dont give any errors.

Comment: Tangentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57906169

Comment: Does this only happen when you use the ```iframe``` or does it also occur when you access the Apps Script Web App?

Comment: only in the iframe, my understanding it that there should at least the google access denied page be displayed. But for me its only a white screen

Comment: Does script editor> executions tab show a doGet being triggered at the time you open the iframed page?

Comment: Yea I am stupid I did not see the error, I fixt it now and now I have the outcome that I need to be logged in. I updated the question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: It was alot of Cross origin errors because I did not deploy the latest version.

Comment: If the user is not logged in but he tries to access the actual Web App rather than the ```iframe``` do you still get the same thing? Are you getting any error messages in the browser console this time? Could you also show the image you are refferring to in the question *without adding any sensitive data*? Thanks ! :D

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I updated the question with a link, there you can exactly see the image  I also have and error in the web console

Comment: I see. If you try this just with the Web App (not embedded iframe) are you still getting the same screen?

Comment: no, when I try this without iframe and I am not logged into google the google signin pops up and when I successfully sign in the webapp is been displayed

Comment: Hi ! So I have reproduced your issue and I encountered the same behaviour if I did try to access with the account that created this Web App. However, everything worked correctly when using other accounts. If you access with another account are you still experiencing the same problem?

Comment: NOTE: the second account is from a different domain

Comment: So, are you basically want to implement an iframe in one web app of one domain into the web app of another domain? I have tested that now and it worked correctly. Which sharing settings do you use when publishing both Web Apps?

Comment: Well it works if you are already logged in, but if you are not logged it it does not work and you do not get a google sign in redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When publishing web-apps with access: "anyone", it is needed for the end user to be logged in. Otherwise, the user is redirected to Google login page. Google's login page does not allow itself to be iframed. If you're logged in, the web app isn't redirected to Google's login page and this error doesn't appear, else it appears.

#### Possible solutions:

- Warn users beforehand that they must login
- Publish using access: "Anyone even anonymous"
- If that's not possible, It is possible to detect whether the iframed page has window loaded or not using `window.length`(one of the few properties that is accessible cross origin), which will be 0 if page  refused to connect and more than 0 in a web-app, because your page is iframed. Then  it is possible to redirect the user to the login page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    body
    <iframe
      src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/[SCRIPT_ID]/exec"
      >Loading
    </iframe>
    <script>
      (() => {
        console.log("loading page");
        const f = document.querySelector("iframe");
        f.onload = (e) => {
          console.log("iframe onload");
          const fw = f.contentWindow;
          if (fw.length > 0) console.info("logged in");
          else {
            alert("Please Login!");
            window.location = "https://accounts.google.com";
          }
        };
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### References:

- [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)